# how to put a divider char between a number string in javascript for example I have 123456 and I want to be 123,456 or 1000000 to 1,000,000

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put a price on something and I get a string number and it should be divided by every 3 letters
but what eve I try to do I can't
is there any function or way that could be helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using [`Number#toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) with a locale. The locale `en-US` uses commas to delimit every third digit and a dot to delimit the decimal fractional part.

```js
const n = 1000000
const fractional = 12345.67

console.log(n.toLocaleString('en-US')) // 1,000,000
console.log(fractional.toLocaleString('en-US')) // 12,345.67
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```js
    function numWithCommas(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }


    console.log(numWithCommas(100000));
```